# How do I restore default settings of an application in Gtk (set all the widgets to the state as if the application was restarted)?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I would like to implement a button "New" that would work the same as File>New in most applications - that is: resets all the labels, treeviews, etc. to the original state.

Thank you, Tomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widgets don't remember their original state; you have to set them all back one by one. Give labels their original text, clear the tree views by setting their model to `None`.

Perhaps it is better to destroy your window and rebuild it from your Glade file if you have one?